# How do I associate the id of a custom field or the content of a wordpress post to a bootstrap modal?

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, modal-dialog

I try to briefly explain my problem:

I have some blocks of text (the content) that I show with excerpt in a wordpress loop.
In the wordpress function file I inserted a button (read more) that shows all the content in bootstrap modal:

```
function excerpt ($limit) {
$id = get_the_ID ();
$excerpt = explode ('', get_the_excerpt (), $limit);
if (count ($excerpt)> = $limit) {
    array_pop ($excerpt);
    $excerpt = implode ("", $excerpt) .'... <button id = "myModal- '. $id.'" type = "button" class = "btn btn-light btn-sm" data-bs-toggle = "modal" data-bs-target = "#myModal">Open</button>';
} else {
    $excerpt = implode ("", $excerpt);
}
$excerpt = preg_replace ('`[[^]] *]`', '', $excerpt);
return $excerpt;}
```

to the modal I associated the id of the contents:

```
<div class = "pt-cv-ctf-list">
            <? php echo excerpt (50); ?>
        </div>
    <div id = "myModal" class = "modal" tabindex = "- 1" role = "dialog" aria-labeledby = "myModalLabel" aria-hidden = "true">
        <div class = "modal-dialog">
            <div class = "modal-content">
                <div class = "modal-header">
                    <h5 class = "modal-title" id = "myModalLabel"> <? php the_title (); ?> </h5>
                    <button type = "button" class = "btn-close" data-bs-dismiss = "modal" aria-label = "Close"> </button>
                </div>
                <div class = "modal-body">
                    <? php the_content (); ?>
                </div>
                <div class = "modal-footer">
                    <button type = "button" class = "btn btn-default" data-bs-dismiss = "modal"> Close </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The code works but it shows me only the first contents (rightly because I have no associated ID), but if I associate it:

```
<div id = "myModal- '. $ id.'" class = "modal" tabindex = "- 1" role = "dialog" aria-labeledby = "myModalLabel" aria-hidden = "true">
```

it doesn't work and the google console gives me this error:

bootstrap.min.js? ver = 5.9.3: 6 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'classList')

Where am I wrong?

The button I inserted in a function in the wordpress functions.php file and the modal under the div of the excerpt as you can see from the snippets above. Should I include it in the footer perhaps?

Comment: please note, the button you create in php has data-attribute `data-bs-target="#myModal"`; that needs to be dynamic too, as in `data-bs-target="#myModal-' . $id . '"` otherwise it will always refer to the same content.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the error comes when I add the reference id, #myModal - '. $ Id' ..
Yet the id gives it to me correct, if I print an echo $ id, the id finds it correctly

Comment: I mean inside your `function excerpt() { .... }`, at the end of this line: `$excerpt = implode ("", $excerpt) .'... <button ..........` that's where you should modify the `data-bs-target` attribute

Comment: I put it right inside that function and it shows me error

Comment: I think buttons and modals are using the same ID. Please change `<button id = "myModal- '` to something like `<button id = "myBtnModal- '`

Comment: to summarize, button should be like this: `<button id = "myBtnModal- '. $id.'" type = "button" class = "btn btn-light btn-sm" data-bs-toggle = "modal" data-bs-target = "#myModal-' . $id  . '">Open</button>` and modal container should be: `<div id = "myModal- '. $ id.'" class = "modal" tabindex = "- 1" role = "dialog" aria-labeledby = "myModalLabel" aria-hidden = "true">`

Comment: I have finally solved the problem.
By setting the button's data-bs-target and modal id to #myModal - '<? php echo $ id.'?> The modals display their related articles without problems.
The mistake earlier was that I was loading two bootstrap libraries (without realizing it).
Thanks GraphiCode for the support :)